# Embedding interactive ggplotly chart on website

Tags: html, r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

I have created an interactive chart with ggplotly in R, but now am unsure how to embed this in a website. How do I get the html code for the interactive chart? Do I need to knit it? Or is there a way to get the standalone html code without kniting the entire file?

Comment: I think it might be useful: [Using Plotly Offline in R](https://plot.ly/r/offline/)

Comment: You can embed the standalone html file in an iframe: `<iframe src="myplot.html" style="position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%"></iframe>`